# Incorrect results while trying to sort the keys in the object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to sort an object in the decreasing order which looks as follows:

```js
const searchResults = {
  "great": {
    "length": 5,
    "occurance": 301487430,
    "rank": -1
  },
  "read": {
    "length": 4,
    "occurance": 322331766,
    "rank": 10
  },
  "creditors": {
    "length": 9,
    "occurance": 3211591,
    "rank": -1
  }
}

// The way I am trying to sort is as follows:

let keys = Object.keys(searchResults);
let sortByEM = keys.sort((a, b) => Number(searchResults[b.rank]) - Number(searchResults[a.rank]));

console.log(sortByEM);
```

The output should be `read` first and then `great`/`creditors` but currently the output is `great` , `read` and `creditors`. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: @connexo How could I sort this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You tried to access the properties in the wrong way. Instead of

```
searchResults[b.rank]
```

you are looking for

```
searchResults[b].rank
```

Your code `searchResults[b.rank]` is trying to access the property name returned by the expression `b.rank` which of course is undefined (because `b` is just a `string` here). `searchResults.undefined` ofc is also undefined, so your sorting function tries to subtract `undefined` from `undefined` - essentially this means that your sort function does nothing.

```js
const searchResults = {
  "great": {
    "length": 5,
    "occurance": 301487430,
    "rank": -1
  },
  "read": {
    "length": 4,
    "occurance": 322331766,
    "rank": 10
  },
  "creditors": {
    "length": 9,
    "occurance": 3211591,
    "rank": -1
  }
}

let keys = Object.keys(searchResults);
let sortByEM = keys.sort((a, b) => (searchResults[b].rank - searchResults[a].rank));

console.log(sortByEM);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the object wrong.

Instead of `searchResults[b.rank]` it should be `searchResults[b].rank`.